# Nuget exceptions in Artifactory

Tags: nuget, artifactory

I keep getting these kind of exceptions in Artifactory when downloading Nuget packages.
I did some googling but to no avail.
Does anyone know what could be causing them?
Any help would be appreciated.

```
[http-nio-8081-exec-4917] [ERROR] (o.a.a.n.r.NuGetV3VirtualAndRemoteCommon:458) - must have at least one page item
java.lang.IllegalStateException: must have at least one page item
    at org.artifactory.addon.nugetv3.repo.NuGetV3VirtualRepoHandler.collectAllRegistrationResultPageItems(NuGetV3VirtualRepoHandler.java:239)
    at org.artifactory.addon.nugetv3.repo.NuGetV3VirtualRepoHandler.registration(NuGetV3VirtualRepoHandler.java:68)
    at org.jfrog.repomd.nugetv3.rest.NuGetV3SubResource.registrationGzSemVer2(NuGetV3SubResource.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor471.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    ...
```

Comment: You might have more luck contacting Artifactory support. NuGet is implemented in .NET, so this java stack trace is clearly a server side error. If you're not running the newest version of Artifactory, I'd try upgrading first.

Comment: Provide the details of what package you're trying to resolve and Artifactory and NuGet client version information, i can help you based on this information

Comment: Hi Tatarao,
an example package is nugetorg-remote:.nuGetV3/registration-semver2/microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegeneration.utils/index.json
We are using Artifactory v6.16.0 and Nuget command line client v5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error last week. It happened when a user was trying to download packages from a NuGet v2 feed, but configured the source in their NuGet.config with `protocolVersion="3"`. After this was remedied and all the NuGet caches cleared, the exception did not occur anymore and the user could download their packages.